# Convert large hex string to decimal string

Tags: c++, arbitrary-precision, base-conversion

I need to convert a large (too large for the built-in data types) hex string to a string with it's decimal representation. For example:

```
std::string sHex = "07AA17C660F3DD1D2A1B48F1B746C148";
std::string sDec; // should end up with: "10187768649047767717933300899576725832"
```

I'm currently using the [c++ BigInt Class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/) which offers a very easy way to achieve this (but is GPL only):

```
BigInt::Vin vbiTemp(sHex, 16);
sDec = vbiTemp.toStrDec();
```

Is there simple way to do this conversion without a 3rd party arithmetic library? Or can you recommend a free (non-GPL) alternative with similar simplicity (efficiency is irrelevant)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, here is a generic base converter class. I wrote the original implementation in C#, and converted this now to C++. It's .NET origins may still shine through. Feel free to use it as you see fit.

You could use it like this:

```
const BaseConverter& hex2dec = BaseConverter::HexToDecimalConverter();
std::cout << hex2dec.Convert("07AA17C660F3DD1D2A1B48F1B746C148");
```

The output will be:

```
10187768649047767717933300899576725832
```

The class isn't limited to hex digits, but will happily translate between any base, using any base digit encoding.

### API

- `BaseConverter::BaseConverter(const std::string& sourceBaseSet, const std::string& targetBaseSet);`

  Constructs a new BaseConverter instance. The class translates between numbers represented in a *source* number base to a *target* number base.

  The constructor takes two *string* arguments to specify the symbols to be used for the source and target number bases. The first character in the string has value *0*, the 2nd has value *1*, and so on. Example: the symbols for an octal number base are typically `"01234567"`, and for hexadecimal `"0123456789ABCDEF"`. Any printable ASCII character may be used for a symbol, so you could eg. use `"OI"` (instead of `"01"`) for a binary system.

  **Note**: the base symbols are *case sensitive*, so the symbols `"0123456789abcdef"` will *not* decode hexadecimal numbers using upper-case characters.
- `std::string BaseConverter::Convert(std::string value) const;`
  `std::string BaseConverter::Convert(const std::string& value, size_t minDigits) const;`

  Converts number `value` in the source number base into the target number base and returns the result. The 2nd overload takes an additional parameter `minDigits` to specify the minimum number of digits in the result. The returned value will be padded by prepending zero or more symbols having value *0* in the target number base.
- `std::string BaseConverter::FromDecimal(unsigned int value) const;`
  `std::string BaseConverter::FromDecimal(unsigned int value, size_t minDigits) const;`

  Converts an *unsigned int* decimal number to the target number base.
- `unsigned int BaseConverter::ToDecimal(std::string value) const;`

  Converts a number in the source number system to a decimal *unsigned int*. **Note**: the result will be wrong if the decimal value of the number in the source base system exceeds UINT_MAX.
- `static const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::DecimalToBinaryConverter();`
  `static const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::BinaryToDecimalConverter();`
  `static const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::DecimalToHexConverter();`
  `static const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::HexToDecimalConverter();`

  Convenience functions returning instances of `BaseConverter` suitable to convert between common number bases. **Note**: upper-case characters A - F are used for the hexadecimal number base.

### BaseConverter.h:

```
// Arbitrary precision base conversion by Daniel Gehriger <gehriger@linkcad.com>   

#include <string>

class BaseConverter
{
public:
    std::string GetSourceBaseSet() const { return sourceBaseSet_; }
    std::string GetTargetBaseSet() const { return targetBaseSet_; }
    unsigned int GetSourceBase() const { return (unsigned int)sourceBaseSet_.length(); }
    unsigned int GetTargetBase() const { return (unsigned int)targetBaseSet_.length(); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceBaseSet">Characters used for source base</param>
    /// <param name="targetBaseSet">Characters used for target base</param>
    BaseConverter(const std::string& sourceBaseSet, const std::string& targetBaseSet);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a base converter for decimal to binary numbers
    /// </summary>
    static const BaseConverter& DecimalToBinaryConverter();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a base converter for binary to decimal numbers
    /// </summary>
    static const BaseConverter& BinaryToDecimalConverter();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a base converter for decimal to binary numbers
    /// </summary>
    static const BaseConverter& DecimalToHexConverter();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a base converter for binary to decimal numbers
    /// </summary>
    static const BaseConverter& HexToDecimalConverter();

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a value in the source number base to the target number base.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value in source number base.</param>
    /// <returns>Value in target number base.</returns>
    std::string  Convert(std::string value) const;


    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a value in the source number base to the target number base.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value in source number base.</param>
    /// <param name="minDigits">Minimum number of digits for returned value.</param>
    /// <returns>Value in target number base.</returns>
    std::string Convert(const std::string& value, size_t minDigits) const;

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a decimal value to the target base.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Decimal value.</param>
    /// <returns>Result in target base.</returns>
    std::string FromDecimal(unsigned int value) const;

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a decimal value to the target base.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Decimal value.</param>
    /// <param name="minDigits">Minimum number of digits for returned value.</param>
    /// <returns>Result in target base.</returns>
    std::string FromDecimal(unsigned int value, size_t minDigits) const;

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert value in source base to decimal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value in source base.</param>
    /// <returns>Decimal value.</returns>
    unsigned int ToDecimal(std::string value) const;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Divides x by y, and returns the quotient and remainder.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="baseDigits">Base digits for x and quotient.</param>
    /// <param name="x">Numerator expressed in base digits; contains quotient, expressed in base digits, upon return.</param>
    /// <param name="y">Denominator</param>
    /// <returns>Remainder of x / y.</returns>
    static unsigned int divide(const std::string& baseDigits, 
                               std::string& x, 
                               unsigned int y);

    static unsigned int base2dec(const std::string& baseDigits,
                                 const std::string& value);

    static std::string dec2base(const std::string& baseDigits, unsigned int value);

private:
    static const char*  binarySet_;
    static const char*  decimalSet_;
    static const char*  hexSet_;
    std::string         sourceBaseSet_;
    std::string         targetBaseSet_;
};
```

### BaseConverter.cpp:

```
// Arbitrary precision base conversion by Daniel Gehriger <gehriger@linkcad.com>   

#include "BaseConverter.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>


const char* BaseConverter::binarySet_ = "01";
const char* BaseConverter::decimalSet_ = "0123456789";
const char* BaseConverter::hexSet_ = "0123456789ABCDEF";

BaseConverter::BaseConverter(const std::string& sourceBaseSet, const std::string& targetBaseSet) 
    : sourceBaseSet_(sourceBaseSet)
    , targetBaseSet_(targetBaseSet)
{
    if (sourceBaseSet.empty() || targetBaseSet.empty())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid base character set");
}

const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::DecimalToBinaryConverter()
{
    static const BaseConverter dec2bin(decimalSet_, binarySet_);
    return dec2bin;
}

const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::BinaryToDecimalConverter()
{
    static const BaseConverter bin2dec(binarySet_, decimalSet_);
    return bin2dec;
}

const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::DecimalToHexConverter()
{
    static const BaseConverter dec2hex(decimalSet_, hexSet_);
    return dec2hex;
}

const BaseConverter& BaseConverter::HexToDecimalConverter()
{
    static const BaseConverter hex2dec(hexSet_, decimalSet_);
    return hex2dec;
}

std::string BaseConverter::Convert(std::string value) const
{
    unsigned int numberBase = GetTargetBase();
    std::string result;

    do
    {
        unsigned int remainder = divide(sourceBaseSet_, value, numberBase);
        result.push_back(targetBaseSet_[remainder]);
    }
    while (!value.empty() && !(value.length() == 1 && value[0] == sourceBaseSet_[0]));

    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

std::string BaseConverter::Convert(const std::string& value, size_t minDigits) const
{
    std::string result = Convert(value);
    if (result.length() < minDigits)
        return std::string(minDigits - result.length(), targetBaseSet_[0]) + result;
    else
        return result;
}

std::string BaseConverter::FromDecimal(unsigned int value) const
{
    return dec2base(targetBaseSet_, value);
}

std::string BaseConverter::FromDecimal(unsigned int value, size_t minDigits) const
{
    std::string result = FromDecimal(value);
    if (result.length() < minDigits)
        return std::string(minDigits - result.length(), targetBaseSet_[0]) + result;
    else
        return result;
}

unsigned int BaseConverter::ToDecimal(std::string value) const
{
    return base2dec(sourceBaseSet_, value);
}

unsigned int BaseConverter::divide(const std::string& baseDigits, std::string& x, unsigned int y)
{
    std::string quotient;

    size_t lenght = x.length();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lenght; ++i)
    {
        size_t j = i + 1 + x.length() - lenght;
        if (x.length() < j)
            break;

        unsigned int value = base2dec(baseDigits, x.substr(0, j));

        quotient.push_back(baseDigits[value / y]);
        x = dec2base(baseDigits, value % y) + x.substr(j);
    }

    // calculate remainder
    unsigned int remainder = base2dec(baseDigits, x);

    // remove leading "zeros" from quotient and store in 'x'
    size_t n = quotient.find_first_not_of(baseDigits[0]);
    if (n != std::string::npos)
    {
        x = quotient.substr(n);
    }
    else
    {
        x.clear();
    }

    return remainder;
}

std::string BaseConverter::dec2base(const std::string& baseDigits, unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int numberBase = (unsigned int)baseDigits.length();
    std::string result;
    do 
    {
        result.push_back(baseDigits[value % numberBase]);
        value /= numberBase;
    } 
    while (value > 0);

    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

unsigned int BaseConverter::base2dec(const std::string& baseDigits, const std::string& value)
{
    unsigned int numberBase = (unsigned int)baseDigits.length();
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < value.length(); ++i)
    {
        result *= numberBase;
        int c = baseDigits.find(value[i]);
        if (c == std::string::npos)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid character");

        result += (unsigned int)c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!
Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can use this function to convert a Hex char to a decimal char:

```
void Hex2Char(const char* szHex, unsigned char& rch)
{
    rch = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(*(szHex + i) >='0' && *(szHex + i) <= '9')
            rch = (rch << 4) + (*(szHex + i) - '0');
        else if(*(szHex + i) >='A' && *(szHex + i) <= 'F')
            rch = (rch << 4) + (*(szHex + i) - 'A' + 10);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

than you can use that to convert a string:

```
void HexStrToCharStr(const char* hexStr, unsigned char* decStr, int n)
{
    unsigned char d_ch;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        Hex2Char(hexStr+2*i, d_ch);
        decStr[i] = d_ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only give me an array with the decimal values of each char in the hex-string, but I need to convert the entire string as one number. Adding all the values is not possible because the end result will be too big for regular integers.

Answer (score -4):

std::istringstream (sHex ) >> std::hex >> sDec;

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, sDec get's set to the same value as sHex.

Comment: Did you test the sample input and output provided in the question?

Comment: Yes, a shorter hex string ("std::istringstream ( "2A" ) >> std::hex >> sDec") results in the same behaviour.

Comment: @Flavio: I was asking Ashirius.